# Received "No such file or directory" error message from dockerized nginx

Tags: linux, dockerfile

I've dockerized my frontend project with Nginx as well as related configuration. When I curl the web app on the local server or within the container I get a 404 error page.

First of all, I built a customized docker image by a Dockerfile by copying all directories and config files within the image as follows:

```
FROM nginx
COPY project/webapp /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY project/api /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
```

Then, I ran a container from the image:

```
run --rm -itd -p 8000:80 customized_nginx
```

as I explained, everything is OK but from another host, I get the following error message of Nginx:

```
022/05/31 16:52:56 [error] 37#37: *9 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.12.162, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.12.160:8000"
2022/05/31 16:52:56 [error] 37#37: *9 open() "/etc/nginx/html/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.12.162, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.12.160:8000"
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does `docker run --rm customized_nginx ls /usr/share/nginx/html/api/` show the file?

Comment: Yes, everything is OK. I'm wondering why is not reachable out of the server.

Comment: If the file exists (and _continues to exist_ while the container is running – you should verify this using `docker exec` to spawn a shell inside the container), the only explanation I can think of is a chroot. What does your `nginx.conf` look like?

Comment: The `nginx.conf` is on the `/etc/nginx/` directory. This conf file is OK and from the server as well as the container responses 200, but from another host shows 404. It's bizzare.